# React Native Touchable Opacity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this code, in which TouchableOpacity is not working and i don't know why:

```
const Box = (props) => {
  return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {props.callBackProp(); props.budCallBackProp(props.name)}}>
          <View style={styles.inputBox}>
            <Text style={styles.testText}>{props.name}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>    
  );
}
```

What is wrong here?

Edit:

At first, i click on this blue button with "budynek" text inside it, which opens something that looks like a list. Then after i click on some option i want it to dissapear, which is what these callbacks are for. I wrapped each option in this TouchableOpacity component but nothing happens after i click it - there is no effect of a click. A view which holds these "Box" component is absolutely positioned. Here is rest of the code:

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.rozwijanaPoz}>
      <Pusty/>
      <Box name={"budynek 1"} callBackProp={props.callBack} budCallBackProp={props.budCallBack}/>
      <Box name={"budynek 2"} callBackProp={props.callBack} budCallBackProp={props.budCallBack}/>
      <Box name={"budynek 3"} callBackProp={props.callBack} budCallBackProp={props.budCallBack}/>
    </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
rozwijanaPoz: {
position: "absolute",
left: 60,
},
});
```

And the main container:

```
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIsVisible(true)}>
      <View style={styles.budynekContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.budynekTekst}>{budynekText}</Text>
        {isVisible ? 
          <Rozwijana callBack={visibleCallBack} budCallBack={budynekCallBack}/>
         : null}
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you tell use what error did you get ?

Comment: @docmurloc I edited question, to give more information. I tried zIndex but it didn't help